# Fitting each estimator of a BaggingClassifier separately

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there any way I could `partial_fit` each `estimator` of a `BaggingClassifier` one by one?
Something like this:

```
estim = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=MLPClassifier(), n_estimators=33)
for model in estim:
    model.partial_fit(X, Y)
```

In my real code each `partial_fit` of each `estimator` would be done with different data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you fit BaggingClassifier, you can access the list of its estimators: `clf.estimators_`

Fit them with a usual `fit`:

```
estim = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=MLPClassifier(), n_estimators=33)
for model in estim.estimators_:
    model.fit(X, Y)
```

More in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html#sklearn-ensemble-baggingclassifier).

Comment: Thanks for answering! But what I'm looking for is to access each estimator before fitting

Comment: I guess they are not created before fitting. But when you rerun the fit on each model, the fitting starts from scratch. It implies that the result is the same as if you first fit them and then put into bagging classifier.

Comment: So, just to be clear. All bagging does is just collecting given classifiers together and training them on random data sub-samples. When you access the classifiers independently, you ruin this randomness. But if what you really want is first pretrain a set of models and then put them into bagging, try using warm_start=True with bagging.

Comment: It says: _When set to True, reuse the solution of the previous call to fit and add more estimators to the ensemble._ What does "add more estimators" mean?